# Vuejs component template not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I have pretty common problem with vuejs i have error:

`Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined`,

but none of the other answers helped me. I know this is a problem with Standalone vs Runtime vuejs version explained [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only), but I am not sure how to solve it or where to look.

So i am trying to make jquery plugin component in vue i have only one .vue
nothing special in it.

Webpack configuration is this:

```
let webpack = require('webpack');
let path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    entry: {
        vuedatepickerrange: [
            './src/index.js'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './../dist'),
        publicPath: 'dist/',
        filename: 'vuedatepickerrange.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                        options: {}
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/,
                loader: 'sass-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
            jquery: "jquery/dist/jquery"
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourcemap: true,
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        }),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ['vuedatepickerrange']
        }),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $ : "jquery",
            jQuery : "jquery",
            "window.jQuery" : "jquery",
            "root.jQuery" : "jquery"
        })

    ]
}
```

I am importing the correct vue library. I'm using webpack 2 so i am importing `vue/dist/vue.esm.js` instead of webpack 1 `vue/dist/vue.common.js` but other than that i think i got everything covered.

Only when i try to include it in other project this happens. When i try my demo example withing the project everything works.

You can see all the code and entire project [here](https://github.com/housefrommars/vue-datepickerrange)

Comment: `export default Object.assign(VueDatepickerRange, { install })` Are you really confident about that line ? Looks odd.

Comment: @Cobaltway yeah that is not the problem i had same issue when i directly included .vue file without index.js

Comment: I don't think I can reproduce. When looking at your example (example/index.html) everything is working fine. https://puu.sh/vRIsu/347c06f4fb.png Note that I don't run in production mode (I removed `NODE_ENV=production` at the start of your npm script because my env does not support it).

Comment: https://puu.sh/vRIE5/1da58f1345.png

Comment: Can you give broken code to see error template? How do u include and what? Only vuedatepickerrange.js?